# Cosa può essere questo "conduttore" che spinge un "decrepito carrozzone"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Gli occhiali d'oro*, di Giorgio Bassani, ho letto:

> Chiudo gli occhi. Rivedo il gran varco asfaltato del viale Cavour completamente deserto dal Castello fino alla barriera daziaria, coi lampioni stradali, disposti in lunga prospettiva a una cinquantina di metri l'uno dall'altro, ancora tutti accesi. Il conduttore Aldrovandi, di cui, dall'interno del tram, non si può scorgere che la gobba schiena irritata, spinge il suo decrepito carrozzone al massimo.

Conosco il significato delle singole parole in questo brano, ma non riesco a immaginare cosa possa essere questo "conduttore" che "spinge il suo decrepito carrozzone al massimo". Qualcuno di voi ne ha qualche idea?

Comment: Il dizionario Treccani, alla voce [conduttore](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/conduttore) riporta “Con riferimento a persona e in senso specifico: a. Chi guida un veicolo…”

Comment: @egreg: Come ho detto in un altro commento, avevo già visto questa definizione del vocabolario Treccani, ma le parole "spinge il suo decrepito carrozzone al massimo" mi hanno fatto pensare che non si trattasse della persona che guidava il tram. Non riesco a capire del tutto bene cosa significhi "spingere" un tram.

Comment: @Charo _spingere_ ha anche il significato di "portare a", e in questo caso "spingere il tram al massimo" secondo me significa fare andare il tram alla massima velocità.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il conduttore Aldrovandi altro non è che l'autista del tram ingobbito al posto di guida.

Il tram viene descritto come un carrozzone decrepito cioè un grosso mezzo pesante e sgangherato che viene spinto al massimo delle sue capacità.

Il verbo spingere qui ha il senso di portare il tram al massimo delle sue capacità.

> [Spingere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spingere/) 3. in senso fig., andare oltre i limiti dell’opportunità, della
>   convenienza e sim.: *si è spinto fino a chiedermi un ennesimo prestito;
>   la sua sfacciataggine si spinse fino a farmi delle proposte disoneste.*

Come fa giustamente notare @DenisNardin un possibile sinonimo di autista più comune oggigiorno in questo contesto sarebbe ***conducente*** invece che conduttore.

Infatti il termine conduttore, riferito ad una persona, si adatta meglio ad un presentatore di un programma televisivo oppure all' affittuario di un appartamento.

Comment: Va detto che in italiano credo che la parola corretta sia *conducente* e non *conduttore*...

Comment: Scusate la spocchia, ma prima di dire che Bassani ha usato un termine non “corretto”, ci penserei su due volte, dopo di che consulterei il [dizionario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conduttore) (“a. Chi guida un veicolo: _il c[onduttore]_ [del barroccio] _salutò i tre aspettati, li fece salire_ (Manzoni); anche di un veicolo in servizio pubblico: _il c. del filobus, del tram_ (ma più com. _conducente_ o _manovratore_).”).

Comment: Ok, ho sostituito con più comune oggigiorno.

Comment: Ma un tram può essere spinto?

Comment: Spingere qui ha il senso di portare il tram al massimo delle sue capacità

Comment: @DaG: Avevo visto questa definizione del vocabolario Treccani, ma le parole "spinge il suo decrepito carrozzone al massimo" mi hanno fatto pensare che non si trattasse della persona che guidava il tram.

Comment: @DaG Mea culpa, avrei dovuto dire *più comune*.

Comment: Potresti spiegare nella risposta quello che significa "spingere" in questo contesto? Penso che il mio dubbio provenga soprattutto dalle parole "spinge il suo decrepito carrozzone al massimo".